# VB.Net - when shall I use "New" word?

Tags: variables, declaration

In declaration of variables and objects, when exactly should I use "New" word, and when shouldn't I use it?
I know that I should declare a string without "New" word:

```
Dim mystring As String
```

I also know I should use it declaring a datatable:

```
Dim mytable As New Datatable()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`New` creates an object that is an instance of the specified class. If you just write the following then you have a reference, but the reference is `Nothing` as you didn't actually create a Datatable for it to refer to:

```
Dim mytable As Datatable
```

You don't typically use `New` for value types (Numbers, Dates, Booleans, Structures, Enums - [a full list is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)), as they always have a value (cannot be `Nothing`). For example this outputs `0`:

```
Dim num as Int32
Console.WriteLine(num)
```

I wouldn't worry too much about this, but some value types (structures) can be initialised with `New`, which is somewhat inconsistent, for example:

```
Dim dec = New Decimal(2, 3, 4, True, 5)
```